# Down-sampling Non-Time Series data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, time-series, resampling

I have two dataframes where both are day-count data with respect to some start time. One dataframe is a signal data sampled at a higher rate compared to the other dataframe signal data. The overall time frame is same for both the signal dataframes. My question is what approach can I use to downsample the one with more rows to match the number of rows. 
the data frame looks like these: (where the first column is day count from a particular start time)

```
    Days  Data at 1hz
0  0.958        83.63
1  0.958        83.08
2  0.958        82.45
3  0.958        81.83
4  0.959        81.18

    Days  Data at 4hz
0  0.958        0.028
1  0.958        0.028
2  0.958        0.027
3  0.958        0.029
4  0.958        0.028
```

I have tried the `pandas.resample()` function but apparently it works for only timestamp index. And also `rolling()`function makes the other values over a window = 8 (diff in sampling ratio of data1 and data2) as `Nan` and does not remove the rows.

Is there a way, I can apply `mean()` or some other approach to make them both of same rows by removing some rows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `rolling` is a good idea what you are missing is a `dropna` after to get rid of the extra rows. Here an example, with 3 rows per Date in `df1` and 8 rows per Date in `df2`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date':[0.958]*3 + [0.959]*3, 
                    'Data_1': [83.63,83.08,82.45,81.83,82.76,84.97]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date':[0.958]*8 + [0.959]*8, 
                    'Data_4': [0.028,0.028,0.027,0.029]*4})
```

Now, you want to remove 5 rows in `df2` per Date to get only 3 rows as in `df1`, you get it with `groupby`, `rolling` and `dropna`. Function `mean` can be changed if you want something else, and `reset_index` is more for cosmetic.

```
df3 = df2.groupby('Date').rolling(window=6).mean().dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
```

which gives the result for `df3`

```
     Data_4   Date
0  0.028000  0.958
1  0.027833  0.958
2  0.028000  0.958
3  0.028000  0.959
4  0.027833  0.959
5  0.028000  0.959
```

with only 3 rows per Date from data in `df2`.

Note that in the `rolling`, `window = 6`, which is the difference of rows per Date between df2 and df1 **plus 1**, otherwise you get one extra row.

Answer (score 0):

an alternative option is to use groupby:

### create data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'days': [0.958] * 100, 'data 4Hz': [*range(100)]})
df
```

**output:**
[image]

### Downsample:

to go from 4 hz -> 1 hz we will downsample using a window of 4, and we use a mean here to downsample, but you can use anything that works with groupby.

```
window = 4
df_1hz = df.groupby((df.index/window).astype('i')).mean()
df_1hz.head()
```

**output:**
[image]